# How to flexible update quantity add to cart in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i am new developer in ROR, i have question to ask about add to cart . i want to flexible update quantity in add to cart. i have code as shown below

Show in my views/cart/show.html.erb

```
<% total = 0 %>
<table>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Price</td>
  <td>Quantity</td>
  <td>Amount</td>
  <td>update</td>
  <% for item in @cart.line_items %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= item.product.name %></td>
      <td><%= item.product.price %></td>
      <td><%= item.qty %></td>
      <td><%= item.product.price.to_f * item.qty.to_f %></td>
      <td>
            <%= form_for 'item', :url => {:controller => 'line_items', :action => 'update', id: item} do |f| %>
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.number_field :qty, :value => item.qty %>
                    <%= submit_tag "Update" %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <td><% total += item.product.price.to_f * item.qty.to_f %></td>
  <% end %>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><%= total %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to "Shopping Continue", products_path %></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Empty Cart', cart_path(@cart), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

when i click submit on button update it show error like this

Routing Error

No route matches [POST] "/line_items/195/edit"

Rails.root: C:/railsapp/shoppingcat_01

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Routes

Routes match in priority from top to bottom

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write out your routes by

```
rake routes
```

command.

I think your problem is the method of the form, is put not post.

```
form_for 'item', :url => {:controller => 'line_items', :action => 'update', id: item}, method: 'put'
```

or

```
= form_for :items, :url => edit_line_item_path(item) do |f|
```

Comment: thank you su much for your answer.when i add method: 'put' it stop errors with routs,but it errors with controller like this: ActionController::ParameterMissing in LineItemsController#update  param is missing or the value is empty: line_item . please help me again!

Comment: How looks like your controller? The routes?